# Force scroll to div when toggled with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the page to jump down to a window that's opened with JQuery, but I'm not having any luck.

This is the Javascript for the row of buttons (each one displays different info in the window) you click to open the window:

```
<div id="individuals-full">
  <h1 style="text-align: center;">Individuals</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#adjustment-content">
        <div id="adjustment-of-status" class="individual-icons">Adjustment of Status</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#asylum-content">
        <div id="asylum" class="individual-icons">Asylum</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="info-panel">
  <div id="adjustment-content" class="toggle" style="display:none">
    <hr/>
    <div class="down-arrow"></div>
    <h1>Adjustment</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div id="asylum-content" class="toggle" style="display:none">
    <hr/>
    <div class="down-arrow"></div>
    <h1>Asylum</h1> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
    voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
    tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</div>
</div>

jQuery("#individuals-full a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery(".toggle").hide();
  var toShow = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  jQuery(toShow).show();
});

function scrollToAnchor(aid) {
  var aTag = $("a[individuals-full='" + aid + "']");
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: aTag.offset().top
  }, 'slow');
}

$("#individuals-full a").click(function() {
  scrollToAnchor('#info-panel');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xmb8a26u/2/

It opens and works fine, but it doesn't scroll down to the window. One other minor issue is that it doesn't close when you click on the button again (it always stays open once it's open). That's not a huge problem but if there's something I can modify to do that as well it would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use .toggle(); Method  in order to open and close the div..
Check the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I did a poor job explaining this, but .toggle breaks it because it will close when the next button is clicked. I did a JSFiddle and also tried to put in my code for the jumping to section part:

https://jsfiddle.net/xmb8a26u/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for smooth scroll

```
// Smooth scroll 
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#info-panel').offset().top + (0)
 }, 700);

**Complete Code**
jQuery("#individuals-full a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();        
jQuery(".toggle").hide();
var toShow = jQuery(this).attr('href');
jQuery(toShow).show();

// Smooth scroll 
  $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('#info-panel').offset().top + (0)
 }, 700);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#adjustment-of-status").click(function(){
 $(".toggle:first").css("display","block");
 $(".toggle:last").hide();
 });
 $("#asylum").click(function(){
  $(".toggle:last").css("display","block");
  $(".toggle:first").hide();
});
 });
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="individuals-full">
  <h1 style="text-align: center;">Individuals</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#adjustment-content">
        <div id="adjustment-of-status" class="individual-icons">Adjustment of Status</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#asylum-content">
        <div id="asylum" class="individual-icons">Asylum</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="info-panel">
   <div id="adjustment-content" class="toggle" style="display:none">
    <hr/>
    <div class="down-arrow"></div>
    <h1>Adjustment</h1> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div id="asylum-content" class="toggle" style="display:none">
    <hr/>
    <div class="down-arrow"></div>
    <h1>Asylum</h1> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
    voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
    tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</div>
</div>
</body>
```